# Posting Message to a Slack Channel using Postman

Tags: java, postman, slack-api

I have created a personal account and created a channel on it. I want to do a POC where I want to post messages on my channel using POSTMAN. How should I do that? If anyone has done this using java code or a POC, Could you help me with the requisite and prerequisite?

I am looking for HTTP methods, headers or all information.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks

Comment: You can refere to Slack APIs https://api.slack.com/web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. Assuming you want to use the API you find all information on the API page for the method [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

There are in general three ways to send requests to API methods:

1. GET parameters
2. POST with as x-www-form body
3. POST with JSON body

I will focus on the 2nd since it is the most common. Here is what you need to enter in Postman:

- Create a new request
- Request: POST with URL: `https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage`
- Body: `x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Enter Parameters for the method

  - `token`: Your API token, e.g. `xoxp-123456789'
  - `channel`: Name or ID of a Slack channel, e.g. `general`
  - `text`: Text of your message, e.g. `Hello, World!`

Comment: I could generate one entire script after reading this documentation. Thank you